# How to pass []*type to function?

Tags: go

I have a method in Golang that requires a []*type as a parameter.
I have a slice:

```
s := make([]myType, 3)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: [Please take the Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). And if your question is: How to pass a **type** to a function as opposed to a **value**, just like `make` and `new` do it; then the answer is: You cannot do that. `make` and `new` are special builtin functions that allow that, but you cannot pass a type identifier to a function you declared.

Comment: If the problem is that the function takes a slice of pointers to a type and you have a slice of that type, you can't pass it because the types don't match. You have to create a slice of pointers to the type and pass that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In short (and as somewhat alluded to by other commenters), it sounds like you're asking how to use a feature that Go doesn't support. Namely, generics: a function with signature `[]*type`, where `type` isn't actually a specific concrete type that you've already defined. While this might be supported in the future, it isn't for right now - you're stuck with defining the function with `[]*specific-concrete-type` for now.